# getAttributes() from a oracle.sql.struct

Tags: sql, oracle, struct, plsql, procedure

I have an oracle.sql procedure with 3 parameters (1 in, 2 out). All of these are customs recordset (Type Object)

My problem is to get the struct attributes in an object[]. If I try this I will get the following exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: Interner Fehler: Image is a collection
>   image,expecting ADT

```
try
    {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Context contextEnv = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) contextEnv.lookup("jdbc/uvs/kpz_web");

    Connection connectionDB = dataSource.getConnection();
     Struct recMitglied = connectionDB.createStruct("KPZ.RECTYPE_MITGLIED",new Object[] {mitglied.ID,mitglied.VID,mitglied.MNr,mitglied.BNr,mitglied.NameFirma1,mitglied.NameFirma2,mitglied.NameFirma3,mitglied.Strasse,mitglied.HausNr,mitglied.PLZ,mitglied.Ort,mitglied.Telefon,mitglied.Email,mitglied.statusKurz});
     CallableStatement cs;  

     cs = connectionDB.prepareCall("BEGIN KPZ.PCK_MITGLIED.PRC_LESE_MITGL_ADRESSE(?,?,?); END;");


    cs.setObject(1, recMitglied);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, Types.STRUCT,"KPZ.RECTYPE_TECHINFOS");    
    cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.STRUCT,"KPZ.TABTYPE_MITGLIED");

    cs.execute();

    STRUCT output_oracle_record  = (oracle.sql.STRUCT)cs.getObject(3);

        System.out.println("SQL-Object type: " + output_oracle_record.getSQLTypeName());


    Object[] return_record_array  = output_oracle_record.getOracleAttributes();

    cs.close();         
    connectionDB.close();      


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Console

> SQL-Object type: KPZ.TABTYPE_MITGLIED java.sql.SQLException: Interner
>   Fehler: Image is a collection image,expecting ADT

I hope anyone can help me
thanks.

Comment: KPZ.TABTYPE_MITGLIED i thing it'is collection. And  so for this param you have to use Types.ARRAY.  
cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY,"KPZ.TABTYPE_MITGLIED");
 ARRAY output_oracle_record  = (oracle.sql.ARRAY )cs.getObject(3);

Comment: You will normally need to map your PL/SQL type (KPZ.TABTYPE_MITGLIED) to a Java type (this requires implementing the SQLData interface). Anyway, take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625901/getting-returned-record-type-from-plsql-function-in-java/42626979#42626979. You will also have to change oracle.sql.STRUCT to oracle.sql.ARRAY.