# Getting Returned record type from plsql function in java

Tags: java, plsql

I have a `plsql` function that returns a record type `challan_rec`.

```
create or replace package xx_bal_api as
    type challan_rec is record (
        challan_number varchar2(40),
        challan_amount number
    );


    FUNCTION get_challan(foo number) return challan_rec;
end;



create or replace package body xx_bal_api as

    FUNCTION get_challan(foo number) return challan_rec
    is
    cr challan_rec;
    begin
        cr.challan_number := '00002154215'; 
        cr.challan_amount := 2265;
        return cr;
    end get_challan;
end;
```

I want to call this function from java code and get that record type in java.
Kindly guide me how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: How did you declare challan_rec type? Is it an SQL or PLSQL object?

Comment: see the update,sorry i forgot to share the package specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets start by correcting your code. I can see that your posted code will not compile and will throw issue. The correct code is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE xx_bal_api
AS
   TYPE challan_rec IS RECORD
   (
      challan_number   VARCHAR2 (40),
      challan_amount   NUMBER
   );

   TYPE rec IS TABLE OF challan_rec index by pls_integer;

   FUNCTION get_challan (foo NUMBER)
      RETURN rec;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xx_bal_api
AS
   FUNCTION get_challan (foo NUMBER)
      RETURN rec
   IS
      cr   rec;
   BEGIN
      cr (1).challan_number := '00002154215';
      cr (1).challan_amount := foo;
      RETURN cr;
   END get_challan;
END;
```

When you execute this code you may face issue like `invalid datatype` . This is because a `RECORD` is limited to be used within `PLSQL`.

```
select xx_bal_api.get_challan(2265) from dual;
```

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

The best way to do this is to create a `OBJECT` and a `TYPE` of the object and then `return` it in your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE challan_rec IS OBJECT
(
   challan_number VARCHAR2 (40),
   challan_amount NUMBER
);
/    
CREATE OR REPLACE Type rec is table of challan_rec;
/ 
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_challan(foo number) 
    return rec
  is  
    cr rec:=rec();

   begin
        cr.extend();
        cr(1):= challan_rec('00002154215',foo);        
        return cr;
   end get_challan;   
end;

/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> select get_challan(2265) from dual;
     /
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can only call functions returning SQL objects from Java, not PLSQL objects. So change your challan_rec accordingly. The whole process should involve 4 steps given below.

1. Create an object type at schema level (not within a package). Also, your type should be of type OBJECT, not RECORD.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Some_schema.chellan_rec IS OBJECT (
   challan_number varchar2(40),
   challan_amount number
   )
   ```

2 . Change your function get_chellan to return this object

3. Implement SQLData interface

   ```
   public class Chellan_Rec implements SQLData{

   //override readSQL, writeSQL and getSQLTypeName methods
   }
   ```
4. Call the PLSQL from Java code

   ```
   ResultSet rs=null;
   CallableStatement stmt=null;
   Chellan_Rec rec = null;
   try{

     String sqlQuery = "{call get_chellan(?,?)}";

   //map plsql type to Java type
     Map m = conn.getTypeMap();
     m.put("schema_name.chellan_rec", Class.forName("some_java_package.Chellan_Rec"));//this maps the Java class to the Oracle custom type
     conn.setTypeMap(m);

     stmt=conn.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
     stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.STRUCT, "chellan_rec");
     stmt.setObject(2, fooNum);
     stmt.execute();    

     rec = (Chellan_Rec)stmt.getObject(1);

   }catch(Exception e){
     //log the exception;
   }
   ```