# Passing 2 field array to oracle procedure from c#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've been trying to pass 2 field data type to oracle procedure from c#. I can do it for 1 field like below;

oracle:

```
TYPE my_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE insert_question(test IN my_array) IS    
BEGIN
   --something
END;
```

C#:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("test", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
        {
            CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
            UdtTypeName = "my_array",
            Value = data_list.ToArray(),
            Size = data_list.Count,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });
```

**It is ok until here.** Now, i need to pass 2 field list to oracle stored procedure like;

- number
- text

I created a new type named for_questions;

```
TYPE fields IS RECORD
(
     num NUMBER,
     text VARCHAR2(1000)
);
TYPE for_questions IS TABLE OF fields INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

and i have a list at c# with 2 field. I've tryed this code for pass data to oracle procedure as parameter;

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("fixed", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
        {
            CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
            UdtTypeName = "for_questions",
            Value = fixed_q.ToArray(),
            Size = fixed_q.Count,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });
```

But it doesn't work as expected. So i need some help. **How can i pass a 2 field list/array to oracle stored procedure as parameter?**

Thanks in advance.

NOTE:Adviced question doesn't helpfull for me because it's on java. My problem is: I can't pass multiple field type as a parameter **in c#.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Returned record type from plsql function in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625901/getting-returned-record-type-from-plsql-function-in-java)

Comment: @XING I'm afraid it doesn't helpfull for me because it's java. And there is "struct" db type there adviced.  My procedure structure is the similar that accepted answer. My problem is; i can't pass the type from c# as oracle parameter.

Comment: I've faced with such problem and i've resolved problem using : http://appsjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html this link

Comment: @MuradGaribzada Yes i saw that actually but it doesn't helpfull for me because i don't have **OracleDbType.Array** type. Thank you.